# Cannot create tizen project in Visual Studio 2015 with Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, tizen

This is my first time of using Visual Studio 2015 Community with Xamarin, and in using them to create Tizen apps.

In Visual Studio 2015, I chose File - New Project - Blank Tizen App (Tizen Xamarin.Forms Single). The files were generated, but virtually every keyword was not recognized i.e. red underline on them.

What configuration is wrong is my system, and how to fix them?

Comment: Installation or re-installation with the C#/.NET (Xamarin v3.1.1) in Cross Platform Mobile Development is recommended. https://developer.tizen.org/development/preview/visual-studio-tools-tizen/installing-visual-studio-tools-tizen Getting started:
https://developer.tizen.org/development/preview/getting-started

Comment: I followed the steps described in
https://developer.tizen.org/development/preview/visual-studio-tools-tizen/installing-visual-studio-tools-tizen

I also downloaded Xamarin Platform from 
https://www.xamarin.com/platform

But stil all my keywords are highlighted as unrecognized. :( 

Can anyone enlighten me on this?

Comment: Worked fine with Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Edition

Answer (score 2):

OK, so I did the following and it fixed this problem (somehow): 
1. Uninstalled VS2015. 
2. Reinstalled VS2015. I encountered installation failure on Roslyn and NDK-R11C. 
3. I Ran VS2015 installer again in elevated mode (Run as Admin) and chose Repair. Roslyn was successfully installed but NDK-R11C was still failed, with the same error as before: Cannot extract the zip file to the target location. 
4. Manually I ran the extraction of NDK using windows' default unzipper. I got unclear error message stating that NDK cannot be expanded. 
5. Using Norton Commander, Extracted the zip file to the same target location. Success. 
6. Ran VS2015, created the blank project. Now NuGet could get the updates, and after that the keywords were properly recognized.

I don't know, though, what was the connection between NDK and Tizen Extension. Maybe the act of reinstalling VS2015 just fixed the problem. At least now I got it now. Thanks all!.

Comment: Seems quite convoluted, but I also had the red underlines. By chance did you figure out how to make a Tizen Xamarin.Forms app in parallel with the other Xamarin.Forms OSs?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's bug of VS plugin. (it's preview version.)
`Project - Unload project` and `Project - Reload project`
I think this should solve your problem.

Comment: I unloaded and reloaded the project, still the same situation occured.

Comment: Please staty tuned, I'm in the process of reinstalling the visual studio 2015 commnity,  and found some error during reinstallation. I'll get back as soon as it fixed.